# SharePoint Workflows - How to associate with specific content types (particularly folders)?

Tags: sharepoint

I noticed when working with SharePoint Designer that each workflow has a config xml with  tags.  Does anyone know how to:
1) Associate the workflow with a specific content type?
2) Know if it is possible to associate a workflow with folders?

Comment: I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/MOSS_FolderContentTypeWF.aspx?display=Print
I think it partially answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to associate workflows with folders.  Apparently Visual Studio created Windows Workflow Foundation (WWF) development is the only tried-and-true way to create custom workflows that can be associated with different content types.  There are some enterprise tools that can help a lot for creating custom workflows such as [K2's Blackpoint](http://www.k2.com/en/displaycontent.aspx?id=901) (though I haven't had a chance to try the software).

I did find a couple of other workflow tutorials to start me off:

- [SharePoint Workflows for Folder Content Type - codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/MOSS_FolderContentTypeWF.aspx?display=Print)
- [Microsoft SharePoint Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/tags/Workflow/default.aspx)

I didn't find any information on the config xml tags yet.